# Play videos fullscreen in landscape (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that is built as a hierarchy of viewControllers.

On of the view Controllers is for a 'video section' of the app.

The app is designed to be portrait only, however, I want to force the videos to play fullscreen in landscape (just like the iPod app on the iPhone).

After searching around, I see that many people have this problem.

I finally have been able to rotate it, but it doesn't work in full screen, that defaults to portrait.

And since it doesn't work in full screen, you see elements in the parent views over the video.

Is there an easy way to rotate this video in full screen, or do I have to broadcast a message to the parent views to hide elements when the video is playing?

here is the code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[recipeData objectForKey:@"videoPath"]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];  

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayer];  


        moviePlayer.controlStyle =   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
        moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
        moviePlayer.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
        moviePlayer.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);

        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  
//commenting out the line below will rotate the video, leaving it uncommented forces it to play fullscreen in portrait
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the method to create the video in the appDelegate and target it whenever the video is launched. This did the trick, keeping it above everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead? it presents a full screen almost modal view Controller to handle the video playing. I use it in >=3.2 version and use a hacked up version of `MPMoviePlayerController` for <3.2

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn;t do the trick either since MPMoviePlayerViewController is a subview of the current view. So you see the parent view's menu above the video. The  [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];   On my original snippet put the video at the highest level, just locked it to portrait.

Comment: Thats an oddity that i can't think of a fix, but using MPMoviePlayerViewController and setting the frame manually to the entirety of the screen would work i believe (it does for me; although it was a lot of trial and error and its fairly sloppy code).

Comment: I put the method to create the video in the appDelegate and target it whenever the video is launched. This did the trick, keeping it above everything else.

Answer (score 0):

For full screen playback you should use MPMoviePlayerViewController and then to make it launch and play in landscape format use the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method on the MPMoviePlayerViewController class.

Looks like this:

```
[yourInstanceOfMPMoviePlayerViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```